# Java integer operations

Tags: java, int, concatenation

My `int` values:

```
    int a= 0x02; int b= 1; int c= 2; int d = 0; int e = 0; int f = 0; int g= 1;
```

How can I concatenate these integers and get a single `int` value?
and the result `int` value should have first 8 bits for "a" and 4 bits each for the rest??

Something like : `2120001`

Comment: "Something like : 2120001" Do you expect that result as a decimal number? That contradicts your first sentence where you talk about bits. So what result exactly do you expect?

Comment: is the data in `a`  possibly occupying 32 bits ?

Comment: WHat are you trying to do because I suspect this won't work the way you think it does. For example `0x02` is just `2` and there is no way to determine the number was defined in hex.

Comment: You don't really "concatenate" `int`s.  You add ints, and concatenate `string`s.  You could convert each of your ints to a string, concatenate them, and convert back to an int, but that result is not even guaranteed to **be** an int.

Comment: "a" occupies 8 bits and the rest 4 bit each

Comment: So you want 0x212001, not 212001. They aren't the same thing. You need to be a lot more precise in this business than just 'concatenate ... something like'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a= 0x02; int b= 1; int c= 2; int d = 0; int e = 0; int f = 0; int g= 1;
int res=((a&0xff)<<24)|((b&0xf)<<20)|((c&0xf)<<16)
       |((d&0xf)<<12)|((e&0xf)<<8)|((f&0xf)<<4)|((g&0xf));
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(res));
```

Yields:
    `2120001`

Comment: It doesn't yield 212001. It yields 0x212001. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
String yourString = "" + a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(yourString, 4);`

Comment: This will not meet the specs of the question, as far as the first 8 bits, the next 4 bits, etc.  For example, the first 8 bits of this resulting `int` will be `00000000`.

Comment: 0x02 = 2. As per the problem, 0x02,1,2,0,0,0,1 = 212001 which is the poster's desired result.

Comment: int a = 0x02;
        int b = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int d = 0;
        int e = 0;
        int f = 0;
        int g = 1;
        String z = "" + a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
        
        int j = Integer.parseInt(z);
        
        System.out.println(j);

Comment: 0x02,1,2,0,0,0,1 = 2120001, not 212001, @MichaelArdan

Comment: I also don´t like this since you are doing a lot of StringBuilder calls between-the-lines just to avoid some highly efficient bitwise operations like shifts and ors (or adds).

Answer (score 1):

***Forget***

With thanks to @MichaelArdan

```
String yourString = "" + b + c + d + e + f + g;
int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(yourString, 4) | (a << (6*2));
```

It interpretes bcdefg as base 4 number, and shifts a to the end.

---

***(Misread the question)***

```
int n = a;
int[] v = new int[] { b, c, d, e, f, g };
int p = 8;
for (int k : v) {
     n |= (k & 0xF) << p;
     p += 4;
}
System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: :D int a = 0x02 would still be considered as 2.

Comment: Here, I also don´t like the using-string-concatenation-operator-to-avoid-doing-the-arithmetic-right nature of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
String s = "" + a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
int concat = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

and read up on the [Java type conversion and promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

Comment: what about "result int value should have first 8 bits for the "a" and the 4 bits each for the rest??"

Comment: Should convert back "s" it to int.

Comment: I don´t like this since you are doing a lot of StringBuilder calls between-the-lines just to avoid some highly efficient bitwise operations like shifts and ors (or adds). A division can be implemented as a series of string manipulations, too, but that would be far from efficient, and far away from the true nature of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following way

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 3;
        int bLength = Integer.toBinaryString(b).length();
        System.out.println("a = "  + Integer.toBinaryString(a));
        System.out.println("b = "  + Integer.toBinaryString(b));
        int c = (a << bLength) | b;

        //System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println("c = "  + Integer.toBinaryString(c));


    }
```

**Output**

```
a = 101
b = 11
c = 10111
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a=2;
        int b=1;
        int c=2;
        int d=0;
        int e=0;
        int f=0;
        int g=1;

        System.out.println(g+(f << 4)+(e << 8)+(d << 12)+(c << 16)+(b << 20)+(a << 28));
    }
```

Result is 538050561, which is 20120001 in hex.

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html for bitwise shift operators.

Answer (score 0):

To yield 212001 you need

```
((((((a*10)+b)*10+c)*10+d)*10+e)*10+f)*10+g
```

which shows you what's going on, or more simply

```
a*1000000+b*100000+c*10000+d*1000+e*100+f*10+g
```

However that contradicts your statement about bit width.

I conclude that what you really want is 0x212001, which is yielded by

```
(((((((((((a << 4)+b) << 4)+c) << 4)+d) << 4)+e) << 4)+f) << 4)+g
```

or more simply

> (a << 24)|(b << 20)|(c << 16)|(d << 12)|(e << 8)|(f << 8)|g